# updateapplicationserver ant task always fail with "WAR file is not currently deployed"

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I used a very basic build file taken from the sample configure-was-derby.xml:

```
<property name="worklight.server.install.dir" value="C:/Worklight70"/>
<property name="config.migration.tool.enable" value="true"/>
<target name="minimal-update">
<updateapplicationserver id="" contextroot="/AreaClienti">
<project warfile="C:/temp/AreaClienti.war"/>
<applicationserver>
<websphereapplicationserver installdir="C:/WebSphere85/AppServer"/" profile="AppSrv01" user="wasuser" password="xxxxx">
<server name="server1"/>
</websphereapplicationserver>
</applicationserver>
</updateapplicationserver>
</target>
```

Recently I was able to reproduce the issue on my laptop installation and I believe I found the cause: please review the following analysis and confirm the results.

I originally installed the war file manually from WAS admin console, and when I run the Ant **minimal-update** with the above build file it failed with the mentioned error

> The MobileFirst Project WAR file is not currently deployed in the WAS
>   profile at ...

Then I removed the manually installed war file and reinstalled it using Ant **install** target.
At this point the **minimal-update** run successfully.

I found out that the Ant installation created into WAS config structure

> profile_root/config/cells/cell_name/nodes/node_name/servers/server1

a new **Worklight directory** containing the **worklight-jee-library.jar** file and a **derby subdir** with the derby driver jar.

Apparently the **minimal-update** Ant task makes a preliminary check on the existence of the **Worklight directory** and it fails if it's missing.
Can you please confirm that this is true ?

Of course the **Worklight directory** is not created by the standard WAS installation process.
So, after a console installation of the runtime war the Ant **minimal-update** always fails!

If I manually add the Worklight dir in WAS config, then the Ant minimal-update starts running just fine.
IMHO, altering in such way the standard WAS config structure is not very clean.
Said that, is it a valid workaround in case we initially install the runtime war with standard WAS admin procedures ?

Furthemore, also the returned error message could have been a bit more clear: please let me know if there is any **debug option** to make the Ant tasks more verbose.

At last, let me ask one further question.

I noticed that the Ant execution writes log files in the directory

> user_root/.mobilefirst_platform_server

Is there any way to redirect those logs into a different dir to avoid the risk of filling up the user root ?

Comment: Can you edit into your question (without exposing anything confidential) the XML segment where you call `updateapplicationserver`? Maybe we can spot what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apparently the minimal-update Ant task makes a preliminary check on the existence of the Worklight directory and it fails if it's missing. Can you please confirm that this is true ?

That's correct.

> Is there any way to redirect those logs into a different dir to avoid the risk of filling up the user root ?

Unfortunately not.